# Joining tables with all rows for each unique column value

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
    | A        |
    +----------+
    | ty_date  |
    | ly_date  |
    +----------+
```

and

```
    | B           |
    +-------------+
    | locationid  |
    | ty_date     |
    | value       |
    +-------------+
```

Let's say `Table A` has ty_date from 1st January till 31st December while `Table B` has ty_date from 1st January till, say, 1st August for each locationid.

I am trying to join the table in such a way that in `Table B` each locationid has all the dates from `Table A` with the field `value` having null values for all future dates.

I tried `FULL OUTER JOIN` ON `A.ty_date = B.ty_date` but I am still missing the grouping logic for each `locationid`

Any help on what approach I can try?

Comment: So, you did something like `select a.*,  b.* from a full outer join b on a.ty_date = b.ty_date`? Have you tried a `right outer join`? Help is tricky when we don't have sample data (e.g. in a fiddle) to work with! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to have a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to produce the complete list of days for each locationid then join it back to table_b to get your values

Setup the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table_a (
    ty_date DATE NULL,
    ly_date DATE NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.table_b (
    locationid INT NULL,
    ty_date DATE NULL,
    value INT NULL
);
```

Add 365 entries to table_a, one for each day:

```
;WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT 1 AS [RowID], CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS ty_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.RowID + 1 AS RowID, DATEADD(DAY, 1, r1.ty_date) AS ty_date
    FROM Dates r1
    WHERE r1.RowID <= 364
)

INSERT INTO dbo.table_a(ty_date)
SELECT ty_date
FROM Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)
```

Add entries in table_b for 3 unique locationid's. One entry for each day until Aug:

```
;WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT 1 AS [RowID], CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS ty_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.RowID + 1 AS RowID, DATEADD(DAY, 1, r1.ty_date) AS ty_date
    FROM Dates r1
    WHERE r1.RowID <= 242
)

INSERT INTO dbo.table_b(locationid, ty_date, value)
SELECT 1,
    ty_date, 
    RowID
FROM Dates
UNION
SELECT 2,
    ty_date, 
    RowID
FROM Dates
UNION
SELECT 3,
    ty_date, 
    RowID
FROM Dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 400)
```

Use the below query to return the full 365 days, one row per day per locationid. The Value column is only filled for values that exist in table_b, otherwise they are NULL

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE,
    @MaxDate DATE

SELECT @MinDate = MIN(ty_date), @MaxDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, MAX(ty_date)) FROM table_a

;WITH AllData AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS RowID, locationid, @MinDate AS ty_date
    FROM table_b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.RowID + 1 AS RowID, r1.locationid, DATEADD(DAY, 1, r1.ty_date) AS ty_date
    FROM AllData r1
    WHERE r1.ty_date BETWEEN @MinDate AND @MaxDate
)

SELECT ad.ty_date, ad.locationid, b.value
FROM AllData ad
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.locationid = ad.locationid AND b.ty_date = ad.ty_date
ORDER BY ad.ty_date, ad.locationid
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1100)
```

Note that MAXRECURSION must be equal to or higher than 365 * the number of distinct locationid values in table_b minus 1

The results:

```
ty_date     locationid  value
-----------------------------
2019-01-01  1           1
2019-01-01  2           1
2019-01-01  3           1
2019-01-02  1           2
2019-01-02  2           2
2019-01-02  3           2
2019-01-03  1           3
2019-01-03  2           3
2019-01-03  3           3
2019-01-04  1           4
2019-01-04  2           4
2019-01-04  3           4
.....
2019-08-31  1           243
2019-08-31  2           243
2019-08-31  3           243
2019-09-01  1           NULL
2019-09-01  2           NULL
2019-09-01  3           NULL
2019-09-02  1           NULL
2019-09-02  2           NULL
2019-09-02  3           NULL
2019-09-03  1           NULL
2019-09-03  2           NULL
2019-09-03  3           NULL
.....
2019-12-28  1           NULL
2019-12-28  2           NULL
2019-12-28  3           NULL
2019-12-29  1           NULL
2019-12-29  2           NULL
2019-12-29  3           NULL
2019-12-30  1           NULL
2019-12-30  2           NULL
2019-12-30  3           NULL
2019-12-31  1           NULL
2019-12-31  2           NULL
2019-12-31  3           NULL
```

See here for a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d93c2f974ed77671bfd46e225f2329a7) demonstrating this.